# Can you inline LLVM bitcode in C compiled by Clang?

Tags: c, llvm, clang

I was looking enviously at the ability to put [inline assembler](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s2) in code compiled by GCC, and I'm wondering if you could do something similar with Clang?  For example is there some way I could complete the definition of a function with [LLVM assembler](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html):

```
int add_two_ints(int a, int b) {
  /* 
   * some bitcode stuff goes here to add
   * the ints and return the result
   */
}
```

Any references, or code to complete the example above would be great.

Comment: Do you want inline assembler for a physical CPU, or "inline LLVM IR"? Inline assembler means the former, but your code snippet indicates the latter.

Comment: It appears that I have my terminology wrong.  Fixing the question.

Comment: clang supports inline *assembly* as well, BTW. As for inlining actual LLVM IR, I agree with Oak that it's a duplicate question

Answer (score 3):

clang supports inline assembly, including GCC's extension where you declare input, output, and clobbered registers:

```
int add_two_ints(int a, int b) {
   int result;
   asm( "addl %1, %2;"
        "movl %2, %0;"
        : "=r"(result)
        : "r"(a), "r"(b)
        :);
   return result;
}
```

Clang also has experimental support for Microsoft's `__asm { }` syntax and intel style assembly.

It does not have any support for including LLVM-IR in C or C++ source. Such a feature would largely be just a novelty as inline assembly is typically for accessing special instructions and LLVM-IR doesn't enable that.

Comment: At least, LLVM-IR gives an access to the intrinsics, explicit alignment annotations and metadata (and none of these is available from C), so such a functionality would be useful.